# Using package siunitx when previewing latex fragments in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

I'm using `siunitx` extensively in my lab reports, but I'm unable to get units to appear correctly when previewing latex fragments.

This is what the latex fragment looks like:

[image: raw]

... with preview applied:

[image: previewed]

The final result is just fine:

[image: rendered]

I've looked at the documentation for `preview-latex`, but it's not clear what I need to add to `preview-default-preamble` or `preview-default-option-list` in order to use a particular latex package in the preview. How do I include packages for use in rendering the preview? In addition, I'm using `\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}` to get the units formatted in the way that I like; is there a way to include this in the list of options?

Answer (score 3):

You can include packages for rendering latex fragments - and all latex export from org I guess - along with their options via `org-latex-packages-alist`. In your case

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("per-mode=fraction" "siunitx" t))
```

This will most likely not help you with the question being 2 1/2 years old, but maybe someone else comes along looking for the same thing :)